# Dynamically create WCF ServiceHost based on parsing Endpoint Address with NamedNetPipes Binding

Tags: c#, wcf

Need a way for one service on a well-known Endpoint to return strings which are relative addresses. The client can then connect to Endpoints using these relative addresses.
Clearly this resembles REST in some ways, but in this case running a Windows Service using NetNamedPipeBinding for IPC, so no need for HTTP.

Don't want to create the Endpoint ahead of time since there will be a potentially large number of relative addresses, only some of which the client would be interested in.

All Contracts are known in advance.

Tried to find a solution with [AddressFilterMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.addressfiltermode.aspx) but wasn't sure how to provision new Binding so that client connected to it, [UriTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uritemplate.aspx) but don't want to use the HTTP framework. Haven't looked into [RoutingService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.routing.routingservice.aspx) because constrained to .Net 3.5.

Pseudocode for client would be something like that below...

```
namespace Testing
{
    class RunTest
    {
        static void Test()
        {
            NetNamedPipeBinding namedpipe = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
            ChannelFactory<Contracts.IRoot> factoryRoot =
                new ChannelFactory<Contracts.IRoot>(
                namedpipe
                , new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/root");
            );
            Contracts.IRoot root = factoryRoot.CreateChannel();
            ICommunicationObject commsRoot = root as ICommunicationObject;
            commsRoot.Open();

            // Service examines address and creates Endpoint dynamically.
            string address = root.SomeFunctionWhichGetsARelativeAddress();

            // IBar service routes endpoint requests internally based on
            // "address" variable.
            ChannelFactory<Contracts.IBar> factoryBar = 
                new ChannelFactory<Contracts.IBar>(
                namedpipe
                , new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/root/IBar/" +
                                       address)
            );
            Contracts.IBar bar = factoryBar.CreateChannel();
            bar.DoSomething();
        }
    } // Ends class RunTest
} // Ends namespace Testing
```

Comment: Is there any reason the strings that the service return have to be relative?  To me this sounds like you could achieve this a little cleaner and easier using metadata publishing and service discovery.

Comment: Do you think System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataResolver would help you? : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.metadataresolver.aspx and this is supported in 3.5 also..

Comment: This kind of thing is possible, but more work than your question suggests. The comment says "// Service examines address and creates Endpoint dynamically". Once a service starts its endpoints are fixed. You cannot add new ones. You could start a new service with the requested endpoints. However if you are juggling a lot of these then you would also need to know when to shut down the child service. Are you willing to go through all that management?

Comment: Just saw that your title says “Dynamically create WCF ServiceHost”. So you problably already see my point about adding endpoints. What’s your algorithm for knowing when to shut down the child services?

Comment: @ErnieL I don't quite get your point. A REST service for example has a root endpoint address e.g. "http://myservice" with paths to resources relative to that address e.g. HTTP GET "http://myservice/resource/1". There isn't a service running specifically at these resource addresses: a single service dispatches calls appropriately so although dynamic may not be the correct term they're not implemented statically. Similarly AddressFilterMode.Prefix gives similar behaviour. I suspect there is a way of going about this using [custom behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx)

Comment: @Mike-C @CSharpVJ Thanks for the suggestions. I'm looking into WS-Discovery although I'm limited to .Net 3.5 so examining sample code. Updated the example to make the "IBar" portion clearer. As I understand it, the mechanism is for services **which are already running** to publish their location. That's not necessarily desirable here. For example when the client does its `new ChannelFactory<Contracts.IBar>(namedpipe, new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/root/IBar/" + address))` could the IBar service re-route that request internally ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AddressFilterMode.Prefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.addressfiltermode.aspx) might suffice. The actual Endpoint used can be inspected in Service methods via 
[OperationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.aspx).[Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.current.aspx).[IncomingMessageHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.incomingmessageheaders.aspx).[To](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messageheaders.to.aspx)

Helper code can parse the endpoint and do any necessary internal processing from there.
Hopefully there's some extensibility on the server side which can simplify that code.

Pseudocode for host:

```
namespace Services
{
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode =
         System.ServiceModel.AddressFilterMode.Prefix)]
    class BarService : Contracts.IBar
    {
        #region IBar Members

        public void DoSomething()
        {
            System.Uri endpoint = System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.To;
            Console.WriteLine("DoSomething endpoint: {0}", endpoint);
        }
    } // Ends class BarService
} // Ends namespace Services
class RunHost
{
    static void HostIBar()
    {
        System.Uri uriBase = new System.Uri("net.pipe://localhost");
        System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost hostBar =
            new System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost(
            typeof(Services.BarService),
            uriBase);
        hostBar.AddServiceEndpoint(
              typeof(Contracts.IBar) // Type implementedContract
            , namedpipeBinding // System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding
            , "root/IBar" //string address
        );
        hostBar.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to stop...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Correction: I'd originally said that this wouldn't treat `"net.pipe://localhost/root/IBar/1"` and `"net.pipe://localhost/root/IBar/2"` as distinct endpoints, but it does. Each causes its own WCF Service instance to be created and called.

An additional change was to encode the data in URL style query parameters and not embed it in the path. E.g.: `"net.pipe://localhost/root/IBar?something=1&somethingelse=11"` and `"net.pipe://localhost/root/IBar?something=2&somethingelse=22"` using [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Message Filters are the way to go. You can use “Prefix” or create a custom.

[WCF Addressing In Depth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163412.aspx)

From the *Message Filters* section of the article:

> ...it uses message filters to determine the matching endpoint, if one
>   exists. You can choose which message filter to use or you can provide
>   your own. This flexibility allows you to break free from the
>   traditional dispatching model when using Windows Communication
>   Foundation to implement things other than traditional SOAP—for
>   instance, the techniques described here enable you to implement
>   REST/POX-style services on the Windows Communication Foundation
>   messaging foundation.

Nice question, by the way. I learned something trying to figure this out.